# Laravel Query builder returning multiple values

Tags: eloquent, query-builder, laravel-7

Code on **page one** view:

```
@foreach($customers as $customer)
    <a href="{{ route('page2',$customer->id) }}">edit</a>
@endforeach
```

**On page one controller**

```
function edit($id){
    $customer1 = Customer::find($id)->get();
    return view('page2', compact('customer1'));
}
```

**My route on web.php**

```
Route::get('page2\{id}', page1controller@edit);
```

Now the thing is id is a primary key so there's no cases of redundancy. However I am getting all the multiple records(all records) on the next page.

**On page2 I need to display value related to the customer clicked on the first page although its showing me all the records**

I checked my db there is no redundant ids.

Comment: Hi Rohan, I would improve your question a bit. Your question is not clear, your referring to a `next` page which isn't explained. Also in your question there is no explaining on what you've tried to resolve the issue?

Perhaps a 
```php
dd($customer1);
```
would provide a bit more details on the content of that value.

Answer (score 0):

On the `find()` function don't put the `->get()`, that's why it returns all values of the `Customer` model.

Check docs [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-collections#method-find) about that function.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to remove `->get()` entirely.

Instead of using `find($id)->get();`, use `find($id);`

it should look like below.

```
function edit($id){
    $customer1 = Customer::find($id);
    return view('page2', compact('customer1'));
}
```

This should return the customer whose `id` is passed as the parameter